# Telling which ruby on rails project is running

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My client wants me to download a working ruby on rails project to my local system. But when I connected to a server, I got nine identical project folders (which seem like different versions). Is there a way to know which project is running using process id (I have only the process id)?

Comment: Can you run console (`rails console`) over there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the process ID, then check /proc/[pid]/cwd symbolic link. This is the process' current directory.

I assume that you are on a Linux-like system.

If you are not, then you may issue a HTTP request (to wake up the rails app) and then look which logfile has been modified recently.

Answer (score 1):

if you are able to run `rails console` on your server then type this: `Rails.root` in your `console` or `irb` it will tell that project you are on belongs to which directory!

Answer (score 0):

no we cant know using process id. but when you start server you will find rails version like

```
:> ruby script/server
=> Booting Mongrel
=> Rails 2.3.10 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
```

above line using rails 2.3.10 version and if you want to know ruby version simply call
ruby -v in your command prompt

Comment: Thanks for your help.But i need to know which project folder is running among a group of projects.